# New changes that I make are not displayed on live site (probably caching)

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, caching

website is live since yesterday, I when I upload website on hosting server and I created .htaccess file for ExpiresByType purpose, and it turned out that it was a mistake because I guess that is the reason why changes do not appear on the site. This is my .htaccess file:

```html
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

  # Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
</IfModule>
```

Website is host on https://www.gandi.net/ and I found that there is The Varnish cache system which prevents the visibility of my changes I  guess.

Here is a PHP script that I called from a browser to clear a particular URL cache - from [this](https://docs.gandi.net/en/simple_hosting/common_operations/varnish_cache.html#purging_cache_using_http_purgepurgeall_request) link:

```html
<?php
/* purge.php
 * Purge a URL on this host
 */
header("Cache-Control: max-age=1"); // don't cache ourself
 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 
// Set to true to hide varnish result
define("SILENT", false);
 
$path = isset($_GET["path"]) ? $_GET["path"] : "";
 
$purge_url = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/$path";
 
if ( $ch = curl_init($purge_url) ) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PURGE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, SILENT);
 
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

Then I noticed that my website is not cached with Varhish because Age is 0. See [image: here]

but changes are not displayed. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I think this is more suited for webmaster

Comment: Also, I want to mention that I tested website on gtmetrix when I tried to optimize images, when optimize single image and upload it again, does not display changes anymore.

Comment: *"when optimize single image and upload it again, does not display changes anymore"* - `ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"` ... ummmm yes? You told the browser to cache it for a month.

Comment: Yes, it is also a mistake, but the same problem happens if I set "access plus 0 seconds" for example. I'd love to be able to deactivate .htaccess at all and try again, I do not know what to do